# beginner: reversing a string with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to reverse a c string. I know of easier ways to do this but I was trying to practice some pointers. This compiles but returns a null string and I do not understand why. What am I missing here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char *forwards, *backwards;
    forwards = "hello";
    backwards = (char*) malloc( strlen(forwards) );
    int i;
    for( i = strlen(forwards) - 1; i >=0; --i )
            backwards[ strlen(forwards) - i ] = forwards[i];
    printf("%s", *backwards );
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will result in:

```
backwards[1] = forwards[4];
backwards[2] = forwards[3];
backwards[3] = forwards[2];
backwards[4] = forwards[1];
backwards[5] = forwards[0];
```

You'll want to change your code to:

```
backwards[strlen(forwards) - i - 1] = forwards[i];
```

In C, strings must end with `'\0'`, so make sure you do:

```
backwards = malloc(strlen(forwards) + 1);
// ...
backwards[strlen(forwards)] = '\0';
```

Also, to print the string:

```
printf("%s", backwards); // no dereferencing the pointer
```

Comment: And a suggestion, instead of calling `strlen(forwards)` multiple times, assign it to a `int len = strlen(forwards)` and use the variable when needed.

Comment: Hey ericbn That worked, thanks. Why do I not need to dereference the pointer?

Comment: And C-String is necessary to end with a null character.

Comment: @mreff555: dereferencing a `char*` yields a `char` which is a single character, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple errors.

First of all the indices calculated are wrong, you should subtract `1` from the backwards index, eg:

```
for (i = strlen(forwards) - 1; i >= 0; --i )
{
  printf("%d -> %lu\n", i, strlen(forwards) - i - 1);
  backwards[ strlen(forwards) - i - 1] = forwards[i];
}

/* prints
4 -> 0
3 -> 1
2 -> 2
1 -> 3
0 -> 4
```

**Mind that there is no reason to have the loop counting down, `for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)` would have worked exactly in the same way**

The second error is that `strlen` doesn't include the NUL terminator so your `backwards` should be allocated as `malloc(strlen(forwards)+1)`.

The third error is the fact that you are not setting the terminator on the reverse string, you must place it by hand, with something like:

```
backwards[strlen(forwards)] = '\0';
```

The last error is the fact that you are dereferencing the pointer in the printf, which you shouldn't do, so it should be

```
printf("%s\n", backwards);
               ^
               no * here
```

Comment: And another problem is repeatedly calling `strlen(forwards)` in the loop when the value doesn't change.